# How to show body and teaser in node--contentType.tpl.php

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-theming

I'm themeing the node template for a particular content type.  I want to access both the main body AND the summary (teaser).  Currently, when I render the body as below, Drupal outputs only the body and not the summary.

As this is a full node page I want both the body and the summary to be rendered.  I can't understand why this isn't clear as day, or am I be missing something about how teaser and body are supposed to work?

```
print render($content['body']);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This works.

```
$body = field_get_items('node', $node, 'body');
$teaser= $body[0]['safe_summary'];
print $teaser;
```